# Table is too large to fit within the textwidth

Tags: datatable, overleaf

I am having a problem  with fitting my huge table within a page.[Here are the current output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlhlZ.png)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}


\begin{tabular}{|lllllllllllll|}
\hline
                                                                                                   & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Li-ion Battery} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Lead-Acid Battery} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Redox Flow Battery} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Sodium-Sulphur} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Sodium Metal Halide} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Zinc-Hybrid Cathode} \\ \cline{2-13} 
Parameter                                                                                          & 2018 & 2025                        & 2018   & 2025                         & 2018   & 2025                          & 2018 & 2025                        & 2018    & 2025                          & 2018               & 2025                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Capital Cost - Energy \\ Capacity ()\end{tabular}} & 271  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(189)}  & 260    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(220)}   & 555    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(393)}    & 661  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(465)}  & 700     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(482)}    & 265                & (393)               \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Power Conversion \\ System (PCS) ()\end{tabular}}  & 288  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(211)}  & 350    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(211)}   & 350    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(211)}    & 350  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(211)}  & 350     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(211)}    & 350                & (211)               \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Balance of Plant (BOP)\\ ()\end{tabular}}          & 100  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(95)}   & 100    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(95)}    & 100    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(95)}     & 100  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(95)}   & 100     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(95)}     & 100                & (95)                \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Construction and \\ Commisioning ()\end{tabular}}  & 101  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(96)}   & 176    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(167)}   & 190    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(180)}    & 133  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(127)}  & 115     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(110)}    & 173                & (164)               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Total Project Cost \\ ()\end{tabular}}             & 1876 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(1446)} & 2194   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(1854)}  & 3430   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(2598)}   & 3626 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(2674)} & 3710    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(2674)}   & 2202               & (1730)              \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Total Project Cost \\ ()\end{tabular}}             & 469  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(362)}  & 549    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(464)}   & 858    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(650)}    & 907  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(669)}  & 928     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(669)}    & 551                & (433)               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{O\&M Fixed ()}                                                                & 10   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(8)}    & 10     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(8)}     & 10     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(8)}      & 10   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(8)}    & 10      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(8)}      & 10                 & (8)                 \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{O\&M Variable ()}                                                             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.03}          & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.03}             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.03}              & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.03}          & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.03}               & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.03}                \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}System Round-Trip \\ Efficiency\end{tabular}}      & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.86}          & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.72}             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.675}             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.75}          & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.83}               & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.72}                \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Response time \\ (limited byPCS)\end{tabular}}     & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{1 sec}         & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{1 sec}            & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{1 sec}             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{1 sec}         & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{1 sec}              & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{1 sec}               \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Cycles at 80\% Depth\\ of Discharge\end{tabular}}  & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{3500}          & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{900}              & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{10000}             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{4000}          & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{3500}               & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{3500}                \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Lifetime (Years)}                                                             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{10}            & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{2.6}              & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{15}                & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{13.5}          & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{12.5}               & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{10}                  \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{MRL}                                                                          & 9    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(10)}   & 9      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(10)}    & 8      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(9)}      & 9    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(10)}   & 7       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(9)}      & 6                  & (8)                 \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{TRL}                                                                          & 8    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(9)}    & 8      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(9)}     & 7      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(8)}      & 8    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(9)}    & 6       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(8)}      & 5                  & (7)                 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I have tried to use the package adjustbox and tabularx, but I cannot get it to work with me.
Also in my code it has a specific problem with the beginning and end of my adjustbox command.

Comment: Please make a [mre] - we need a compilable test document so we can see how wider your pages are etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of potential to make your table less wide, e.g. make the column headers multiline, but even then it is hard to fit it in the very narrow text width of the article class. Either decrease the margins to get more room or show the table on a landscape page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\centering
\small
\begin{tabular}{|lllllllllllll|}
\hline
                                                                                                   & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Li-ion Battery} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Lead-Acid Battery} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Redox Flow Battery} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Sodium-Sulphur} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Sodium Metal Halide} & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Zinc-Hybrid Cathode} \\ \cline{2-13} 
Parameter                                                                                          & 2018 & 2025                        & 2018   & 2025                         & 2018   & 2025                          & 2018 & 2025                        & 2018    & 2025                          & 2018               & 2025                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Capital Cost - Energy \\ Capacity ()\end{tabular}} & 271  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(189)}  & 260    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(220)}   & 555    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(393)}    & 661  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(465)}  & 700     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(482)}    & 265                & (393)               \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Power Conversion \\ System (PCS) ()\end{tabular}}  & 288  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(211)}  & 350    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(211)}   & 350    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(211)}    & 350  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(211)}  & 350     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(211)}    & 350                & (211)               \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Balance of Plant (BOP)\\ ()\end{tabular}}          & 100  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(95)}   & 100    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(95)}    & 100    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(95)}     & 100  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(95)}   & 100     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(95)}     & 100                & (95)                \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Construction and \\ Commisioning ()\end{tabular}}  & 101  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(96)}   & 176    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(167)}   & 190    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(180)}    & 133  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(127)}  & 115     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(110)}    & 173                & (164)               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Total Project Cost \\ ()\end{tabular}}             & 1876 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(1446)} & 2194   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(1854)}  & 3430   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(2598)}   & 3626 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(2674)} & 3710    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(2674)}   & 2202               & (1730)              \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Total Project Cost \\ ()\end{tabular}}             & 469  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(362)}  & 549    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(464)}   & 858    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(650)}    & 907  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(669)}  & 928     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(669)}    & 551                & (433)               \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{O\&M Fixed ()}                                                                & 10   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(8)}    & 10     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(8)}     & 10     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(8)}      & 10   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(8)}    & 10      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(8)}      & 10                 & (8)                 \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{O\&M Variable ()}                                                             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.03}          & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.03}             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.03}              & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.03}          & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.03}               & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.03}                \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}System Round-Trip \\ Efficiency\end{tabular}}      & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.86}          & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.72}             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.675}             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.75}          & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.83}               & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{0.72}                \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Response time \\ (limited byPCS)\end{tabular}}     & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{1 sec}         & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{1 sec}            & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{1 sec}             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{1 sec}         & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{1 sec}              & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{1 sec}               \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Cycles at 80\% Depth\\ of Discharge\end{tabular}}  & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{3500}          & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{900}              & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{10000}             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{4000}          & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{3500}               & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{3500}                \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Lifetime (Years)}                                                             & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{10}            & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{2.6}              & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{15}                & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{13.5}          & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{12.5}               & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{10}                  \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{MRL}                                                                          & 9    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(10)}   & 9      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(10)}    & 8      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(9)}      & 9    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(10)}   & 7       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(9)}      & 6                  & (8)                 \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{TRL}                                                                          & 8    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(9)}    & 8      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(9)}     & 7      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(8)}      & 8    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(9)}    & 6       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{(8)}      & 5                  & (7)                 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```